# Confused how to replaces values in one data frame from another based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Hi guys I have two dataframes below and confused what is the best way to accomplish this

```py
input_df.columns
Index(['Username', 'Full Name', 'Email', 'Department',],dtype='object')

compare_df.columns
Index(['Email', 'Department', 'Username'], dtype='object')
```

What I am trying to do is replace the department value in the `input_df` if Email matches.

So if Email matches in `input_df` and `compare_df` replace the department value in `input_df` with the one from `compare_df`

Not sure how can I iterate over each row and compare this

Comment: `input_df.merge(compare_df[['Department','Email']], on='Department',how='left',suffixes=('_x','').reidex(columns=input_df.columns)` ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. but new edit I need to verify email and username. Some emails are blanks and will fill blanks

```AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'reidex'```

Comment: Sorry its `reindex` and not reidrex typed on a phone. :)

Comment: Same 
```AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-9b60419398bf> in <module>
----> 1 input_df.merge(compare_df[['Department','Email']], on='Department',how='left',suffixes=('_x','').reindex(columns=input_df.columns))

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'reindex'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) + [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
input_df['Department']=( input_df['Email'].map(compare_df.set_index('Email')['Department']) 
                                          .fillna(input_df['Department']) )
```

Comment: hmm can we we make do a dual match of email and username? right now someone has no email and it through a lot of things off.

BUT THIS IS SO CLOSE THANK YOU

Comment: In that case you probably need to use merge as @ anky_91 proposes, could you show an example of your dataframe and the expected output? It is difficult to code without really being able to verify the solution, thank you very much. You're welcome for help! :)